# How to add exceptions in the creation of pdf files according to an excel list using macros

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, pdf-generation, autofilter

Hi I downloaded an excel file with macros that generates pdf files according to a list. There are 2 sheets and the pdf are generated from the sheet called "WEST" to generate them it uses an Autofilter function in column D so it generates a pdf for each unique value specified in the list from the sheet called "PRACTICE".

Here is the link to the file http://nhsexcel.com/filtered-list-to-pdf/

The thing is that I want to add exceptions to the code, for example I don´t want to generate pdf´s of the rows in the sheet "WEST", that contain in column i values less than 10.

I tried to add an autofilter with that criteria but the code keeps saying that it´s not a valid metod.

```
Sub PracticeToPDF()
'Prepared by Dr Moxie

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws_unique As Worksheet
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Dim iLastRow As Long
    Dim iLastRow_unique As Long
    Dim UniqueRng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Note that the macro will save the pdf files in this active directory so you should save in an appropriate folder
    DirectoryLocation = ActiveWorkbook.Path

    Set ws = Worksheets("WEST") 'Amend to reflect the sheet you wish to work with
    Set ws_unique = Worksheets("PRACTICE") 'Amend to reflect the sheet you wish to work with

    'Find the last row in each worksheet
    iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    iLastRow_unique = ws_unique.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


    With ws
        'I've set my range to reflect my headers which are fixed for this report
        Set DataRange = ws.Range("$A$8:$L$" & iLastRow)

        'autofilter field is 4 as I want to print based on the practice value in column D
        DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=4

        Set UniqueRng = ws_unique.Range("A4:A" & iLastRow_unique)
        For Each Cell In UniqueRng
            DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Cell

        Name = DirectoryLocation & "\" & Cell.Value & " Practice Report" & ".pdf"

        ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Name _
        , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

        Next Cell

    End With
    With ws
         .Protect Userinterfaceonly:=True, _
         DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
        True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
         .EnableOutlining = True
         .EnableAutoFilter = True
         If .FilterMode Then
            .ShowAllData
         End If
     End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I would like to just generate the pdf files of all the rows which value in column I is greater than ten, but no matter what I have tried it keeps either generating all the pdfs or not generating any at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want an `IF` statement to check if there are any rows visible (excluding headers) before proceeding with the export.

That's what I do in the code below.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PracticeToPDF()

    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Set dataSheet = Worksheets("WEST") 'Amend to reflect the sheet you wish to work with

    Dim uniqueSheet As Worksheet
    Set uniqueSheet = Worksheets("PRACTICE") 'Amend to reflect the sheet you wish to work with

    'Note that the macro will save the pdf files in this active directory so you should save in an appropriate folder
    Dim directoryLocation As String
    directoryLocation = ActiveWorkbook.Path ' Maybe you should be using Thisworkbook.Path?

    If Len(Dir$(directoryLocation, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then ' Just in case the ActiveWorkbook hasn't been saved.
        MsgBox "'" & directoryLocation & "' is not a valid path. Code will stop running now."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Find the last row in each worksheet
    Dim lastRowOnDataSheet As Long
    lastRowOnDataSheet = dataSheet.Cells(dataSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim lastRowOnUniqueSheet As Long
    lastRowOnUniqueSheet = uniqueSheet.Cells(uniqueSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'I've set my range to reflect my headers which are fixed for this report
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = dataSheet.Range("$A$8:$L$" & lastRowOnDataSheet)

    Dim uniqueRange As Range
    Set uniqueRange = uniqueSheet.Range("A4:A" & lastRowOnUniqueSheet)

    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Uncomment this when the code is working.

    If dataSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        On Error Resume Next
        dataSheet.ShowAllData ' Will throw if filters have already been cleared
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In uniqueRange
        With dataRange
            .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=cell ' Filter for whatever unique value we're currently at in the loop
            .AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:=">10" ' Filter column I for values greater than 10

            ' Only export the PDF if the filter leaves at least one row (not including the header row)
            If .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).CountLarge > 1 Then
                Dim fullPathToExportPDFTo As String
                fullPathToExportPDFTo = directoryLocation & "\" & cell.Value & " Practice Report" & ".pdf"

                dataSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=fullPathToExportPDFTo, _
                        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
            End If
            .Parent.ShowAllData ' Reset the filter for the loop iteration.
        End With
    Next cell

    With dataSheet
        .Protect Userinterfaceonly:=True, DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, _
            AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
        .EnableOutlining = True
        .EnableAutoFilter = True
     End With
'    Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' Uncomment this when the code is working.
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but the problem is that for example if there is a practice in which column I is 0 it still generates a pdf with the headers but without rows, and I would like to avoid the creation of that pdf. I guess my problem is the instruction  "Set UniqueRng = ws_unique.Range("A4:A" & iLastRow_unique)
        For Each Cell In UniqueRng", but I´m not sure how to modify it in order to add the exception

Comment: @Karoconka, have edited my post, if you want to take another look.